# TextView: Get x and y for the end of the last line

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a `TextView` that has multiple lines of text and I want to display an icon at the end of the text of the last line. I have tried a few ways to get x and y values of my textview:

```
      myTextView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
      val layout = myTextView.layout
      val lines = myTextView.lineCount
      val myImage = ImageView(activity)
      myImage.imageResource = R.drawable.ic_icon

      // a few ways I tried
      val possibleY = layout.getLineTop(lines).toFloat()
      streamTitleView.measure(0, 0)
      val possibleY2= myTextView.top.toFloat()
      // same for x value

      myImage.x= //x end of last line of text
      myImage.y= //y end of last line of text

      content.addView(myImage)
    }
```

This does not give me the correct values. So what is the way to get x and y for the text of the last line in a `TextView` so that I can use those values to set x and y for my imageview?

Answer (score -1):

have you ever try to get it using `image.getX()` or `image.getY()`? maybe that can help you to get the position of X and Y coordinate

Comment: No. I don't need coordinates of imageview